# Why can't I serve static files using url_for in Python/Flask/Jinja2 on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, jinja2

I've written this up here: https://gist.github.com/2939061

I can't seem to make this work, despite much searching and trying.

Answer (score 2):

Because bootstrap was cloned from git, and isn't pushing to Heroku. doh!